# Ruby ARGF & RegEx: How to split on paragraph carriage return "\r\n" but not end of line "\r\n"

Tags: ruby, regex, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to pre-process some text using regex in ruby to input into a mapper job and would like to split on the carriage return denoting the paragraph.

The text will be coming into the mapper using ARGF.each as part of a hadoop streaming job

```
"\"Walter Elliot, born March 1, 1760, married, July 15, 1784, Elizabeth,\r\n"
"daughter of James Stevenson, Esq. of South Park, in the county of\r\n"
"Gloucester, by which lady (who died 1800) he has issue Elizabeth, born\r\n"
"June 1, 1785; Anne, born August 9, 1787; a still-born son, November 5,\r\n"
"1789\"\r\n"
"\r\n"    # <----- this is where I would like to split
"Precisely such had the paragraph originally stood from the printer's\r\n"
```

Once I have done this I will chomp the newline /carriage return of each line.

This will look something like this:

```
ARGF.each do |text|

  paragraph = text.split(INSERT_REGEX_HERE)

  #some more blah will happen beyond here
end
```

UPDATE:

The desired output then is an array as follows:

```
[
  [0]  "\"Walter Elliot, born March 1, 1760, married, July 15, 1784, Elizabeth,\r\n"
    "daughter of James Stevenson, Esq. of South Park, in the county of\r\n"
    "Gloucester, by which lady (who died 1800) he has issue Elizabeth, born\r\n"
    "June 1, 1785; Anne, born August 9, 1787; a still-born son, November 5,\r\n"
    "1789\"\r\n"
  [1] "Precisely such had the paragraph originally stood from the printer's\r\n"
]
```

Ultimately what I want is the following array with no carriage returns within the array:

```
[
  [0]  "\"Walter Elliot, born March 1, 1760, married, July 15, 1784, Elizabeth,"
    "daughter of James Stevenson, Esq. of South Park, in the county of"
    "Gloucester, by which lady (who died 1800) he has issue Elizabeth, born"
    "June 1, 1785; Anne, born August 9, 1787; a still-born son, November 5,"
    "1789\""
  [1] "Precisely such had the paragraph originally stood from the printer's"
]
```

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: So in your above example your desired output is what exactly?  An array of two elements?

Comment: this is an example of the file I am using: [file](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/158/pg158.txt)
One approach to simplify matters would be to preprocess the file itself before it is input into ARGF and remove the \r\n on the new lines, but to leave the \r\n denoting the paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware when you do `ARGF.each do |text|`, the `text` will be every single line, **NOT the whole text block**.

You can provide `ARGF.each` a special line separator, it will return you two "lines", which are the two paragraphs in your case.

Try this:

```
paragraphs = ARGF.each("\r\n\r\n").map{|p| p.gsub("\r\n","")}
```

First, split input into two paragraphs, then use `gsub` to remove unwanted line breaks.

Comment: Thanks, this has been very useful! In the example I am wanting to do ARGF.each do  |text |; paragraph = text.split(INSERT_REGEX_HERE) ; #some more code blocks to follow   

Is there a way to maintain this flow? ie, will it be possible to pull in a whole text in the pattern you have described above?

Comment: are you talking about a process flow at the `whole text input` level, or `paragraph` level, or `line` level?

Comment: anyway, you can do `text = ARGF.read` to get the ALL input contents, then do what ever you want.

Comment: I was talking about the paragraph level - but this can be acheived by paragraphs.each do |p|

Comment: one last thing! with the p.gsub("\r\n","") is it possible to also strip non alphanumeric charcaters as part of the same regex, at that point?

Answer (score 0):

To split the text use:

```
result = text.gsub(/(?<!\")\\r\\n|(?<=\\\")\\r\\n/, '').split(/[\r\n]+\"\\r\\n\".*?[\r\n]+/)
```